# Android Java copyFile not working for Gallery Image

Tags: java, android

I have a little camera app that is storing the image to the Pictures folder:

```
File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "preview.jpg");
```

Later I want to copy this Image and save it with a new Filename. Therefore i used this copy function i found here:

```
private void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;
    source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
    destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
    if (destination != null && source != null) {
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    }
    if (source != null) {
        source.close();
    }
    if (destination != null) {
        destination.close();
    }
}
```

The copyFile is called here:

```
        // OLD FILE
        File oldFile = new File(imageUri.getPath());

        // NEW FILE
        File newFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "test123.jpg");

        // COPY FILE
        copyFile(oldFile,newFile);
```

But it is doing nothing. Also no Exception or something. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Full Code

```
public class ParticipateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static String logtag = "Camera APP";
private static int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
private Uri imageUri;
private Bitmap cameraImage;
static final String appDirectoryName = "album name";
static final File imageRoot = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), appDirectoryName);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    imageRoot.mkdirs();
    verifyStoragePermissions(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_participate);

    Button cameraButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.camera_button);
    Button saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button);
    cameraButton.setOnClickListener(cameraListener);
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(saveListener);
}

private View.OnClickListener cameraListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        takePhoto(v);
    }
};

private View.OnClickListener saveListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            savePhoto(v);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(logtag,"Error copying file!");
        }
    }
};

private void takePhoto(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File photo = new File(imageRoot, "preview.jpg");
    //Log.e(logtag,"test");
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}

private Boolean copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
        //Log.e(logtag,sourceFile.getAbsolutePath());
        return false;
    } else {
        //Log.e(logtag,sourceFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;
    source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
    destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
    if (destination != null && source != null) {
        try {
            destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        //source.transferTo(0, source.size(), destination);
        Log.e(logtag,"transfer started");
    }
    if (source != null) {
        source.close();
    } else {return false;}
    if (destination != null) {
        destination.close();
        return true;
    } else {return false;}
}

private void savePhoto(View v) throws IOException {
    EditText input_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_name);
    EditText input_mail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_mail);
    EditText input_phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_phone);
    String name = input_name.getText().toString();
    String mail = input_mail.getText().toString();
    String phone = input_phone.getText().toString();

    if (name.length() != 0 && mail.length() != 0) {
        if (phone.length() == 0) {
            phone = "NoPhone";
        }
        // set fileName
        String fileName = name + "-" + mail + "-" + phone;
       // Log.e(logtag,fileName);

        // OLD FILE
        File oldFile = new File(imageUri.getPath());
        //Log.e(logtag,"Path: " + imageUri.getPath());

        // NEW FILE
        File newFile = new File(imageRoot, "test123.jpg");
        Log.e(logtag,"path: " + newFile.getAbsolutePath());

        // COPY FILE
        if(oldFile.exists()) {
            Boolean copied = copyFile(oldFile,newFile);
            Log.e(logtag,copied.toString());

            // log text
            if(copied) Toast.makeText(ParticipateActivity.this, "Gespeichert!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ParticipateActivity.this, "Konnte nicht gespeichert werden! Kein Foto?", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(ParticipateActivity.this, "Bitte Name und Email ausfüllen!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
        getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_camera);
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Bitmap bitmap;

        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            // Change height of image
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = imageView.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.imageView_height);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            // Hide Label and Button
            TextView uploadText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.upload_text);
            uploadText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Button uploadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.camera_button);
            uploadButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Show Image Name
            //Toast.makeText(ParticipateActivity.this,selectedImage.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(logtag, e.toString());
        }
    }
}

// Storage Permissions
private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};

/**
 * Checks if the app has permission to write to device storage
 * <p>
 * If the app does not has permission then the user will be prompted to grant permissions
 *
 * @param activity
 */
public static void verifyStoragePermissions(Activity activity) {
    // Check if we have write permission
    int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // We don't have permission so prompt the user
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                activity,
                PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        );
    }
}

}
```

Comment: `imageUri.getPath()`. Please tell which path you get.

Comment: `if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
        return;
    }`. Well do you know if this happens? Place a Toast() in it to inform the user: `if (!sourceFile.exists()) {
        { Toast(..... , sourFile.getAbsolutePath(), ...);return;}
    }`. Its important that you show the absolute path to the user! And to yourself.

Comment: `void copyFile()`. You will never know if it succeeded. Make it `bool copyFile()`. And always check the return value.

Comment: `File oldFile = new File(imageUri.getPath());`. Before you continue you should check if oldFile exists before calling that copy function. And use Toast's to inform the user if not.

Comment: the path i get is:
    `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/preview.jpg`
and i the picture is showing up in gallery, but not the copied file. it doesnt exist anywhere

Comment: i also changed the `copyFile()` to a bool, and it is giving me a true. but file "test123.jpg" is still not existing
@greenapps `imageUri.getPath()` and `sourFile.getAbsolutePath()` gives me the same result as written above

Comment: `and it is giving me a true.` Please edit your post with full adapted code. You need READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in manifest file. And on Android 6.0 and above you need to request them at runtime. Now did you do all?

Comment: permissions are allright. i mean... the first file is being created. so it should not be a permission issue?!
you can find the full code above

Comment: `catch (Exception e)  Then put `return false;` after closing in block;

Comment: `"Gespeichert!"` ? You should check `copied` first: `if ( copied) {"Gespeichert!"} else {"@#$%^*"}`.

Comment: thanks, i did both changes. but it is still true and also still not creating any file

Comment: `if (!sourceFile.exists())`. You should really check that before you call `copyFile()`.

Comment: did that, but still no image "test123.jpg". any idea?

Comment: How do you check if the new file exists? You are not using the Gallery app for it is it? You could add some code to check before copy. Just display a toast. Nothing else. Or add code to check existence after the copy.

Comment: `Log.e(logtag,"Error copying file!");` You are throwing away valuable info. Better: `Log.e(logtag,"IOException copying file: " + e.getMessage());` And display a Toast with `e.getMessage()` to the user too.

Comment: i check the filesystem on the device. nothing is being created. `Boolean sourceExisting = sourceFile.exists();` is `true`. but the file is not in the specified folder

Comment: i found my error. or maybe I should say mistake. on the file manager on the phone I can see the file. But I cant see it when I am in the same folder with my computer? why is that?

Comment: So all this time spend for nothing as you checked file existense in the wrong way. You only can do it in code of using a file explorer app on the device it self. You also cannot use the Gallery app. If you will reboot your device you can see the file in the Gallery app and with your computer.

Comment: The computer uses MTP, to talk to your Aneroid debice, which uses the MediaStore which did not yet scan the file.